# How do I find a substring in a string using recursion only?

Tags: python, string, recursion, substring, thonny

So here is my code

```py
def count_occurrences(sub, s):

    if len(s) == 0:
        return 0
    
    else:
        if str(sub) in str(s) and str(sub) == str(s):
            return 1+count_occurrences(sub, s[1:])     
        else:
            return count_occurrences(sub, s[1:])
        
print(count_occurrences('ill', 'Bill will still get ill'))
```

I believe this `if str(sub) in str(s) and str(sub) == str(s):` statement is throwing me off when I run the debugger UI. If I just put `if str(sub) in str(s)` it gives me a number but it is not the number I want which is 4.

Comment: An example and your output would help in better understanding the problem

Comment: Where you have decided that `s[1:]` is the value you should pass to the recursion, what was the intended logic there? Try to explain, in plain English words, the algorithm you want the code to use, and explain why that algorithm should give you the correct answer. Then compare that to the code.

Comment: "it gives me a number but it is not the number I want which is 4." Well, what number *does* it give you? Can you think of a reason *why* it gives you that exact number, rather than anything else? If not, then trace through the logic in more detail. Try to check more of the values that variables have, at varying points in the execution. See https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: input = count_occurrences('ill', 'Bill will still get ill')
output = 21

Answer (score 0):

Your code didn't quite work properly because you skipped one character only if you found the substring that will lead the program to find the substring at the same place, instead you have to skip to the index after the first occurence of the substring. This code will work

```py
def count_occurences(s, sub):
    if len(s) == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        ind = s.find(sub)

        if ind>=0:
            return 1+count_occurences(s[ind+1:], sub)
        else:
            return 0
```

I added 1 to the index because, in the case of "ill", `find()` will give me the index of the letter 'i', so if I give `s[ind+1:]` that will remove all the characters before the first 'l' i.e including 'i', so the next iteration won't find "ill" in the same place as before which leads to counting the same occurence twice.

Answer (score 0):

your condition `str(sub) == str(s)` will never be True, except maybe if the substring is at the very end. You have to compare the start of the string (same length as the substring) instead of searching for it at any position, otherwise you'll count the same match multiple times.  Also, you dont need to use str() if you are already processing strings.

```
def count_occurrences(sub, s):
    if len(sub)>len(s): return 0
    return s.startswith(sub) + count_occurrences(sub,s[1:]) # True is 1
```

Output:

```
print(count_occurrences('ill', 'Bill will still get ill'))

4
```

*Note that I assumed that you want to count overlapping substrings.  For example: 'ana' counts for 2 in 'banana'.*